# Save serial1 to string - help needed

Tags: logging, gps, arduino

I am using an Adafruit Ultimate GPS to logg gps data but want to learn how to save the data to 3 strings and then take out the data I want.

The 3 strings are named

- nmeaRMC
- nmeaGGA
- nmeaGSA

Here is the information I want to take out of the GPS data saved to the strings.

---

$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47.

In the GGA I whant the:

- GPS Fix quality = 1
- Number of satellites = 08

---

$GPGSA,A,3,04,05,,09,12,,,24,,,,,2.5,1.3,2.1*39

In the GSA I want the:

- 3D fix value = 3
- Vertical dilution of precision(VDOP) = 2.1

---

$GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A

In the RMC I want the:

- Time = 123519
- GPS status = A
- latitude = 4807.038,N
- Longitude = 01131.000,E
- Date = 230394

---

Can any one help me With this?

!! The Ultimate GPS sends out RMC,GGA and GSA ones every second !!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `strtok()` to parse these "comma separated strings", using the delimiter `,`.

There are lots of similar questions on StackOverflow already, and many examples on the Internet.

In a nutshell, the first call should be

```
char *token = strtok(nmeaGGA, ",");
```

`token` will point to a null-terminated string of the first field, namely "$GPGGA". For the next calls, use

```
token = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

Note the NULL value. The function will find the subsequent fields in the same string. Skip over the fields you don't want by counting. To convert a string to a number, use `atoi()` or `atof()`.

For latitude and longitude in RMC, use two separate tokens for 4807.038 and N.

Since the numbers of commas is fixed and known for each type of string, you could also parse the strings using `sscanf()` as an alternative.